# Docker error: exit status 255

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm new to docker.I can't restart virtual machine in docker.I don't know what 'exit status 255' means, while running `docker-machine restart vdocker` it shows

```
$docker-machine restart vdocker
Restarting "vdocker"...
Starting "vdocker"...
<vdocker> Check network to re-create if needed...
<vdocker> Waiting for an IP...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available. Last error:Maximum number of retries <60> exceeded
```

running `docker-machine ls` shows

```
$docker-machine ls
NAME     ACTIVE  DRIVER      STATE    URL                       SWARM        DOCKER    ERRORS
default    *     virtualbox  Running  tcp://192.168.99.100:2376              v1.11.2
vdocker    -     virtualbox  Running                                         Unknown   Somthing went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

but default machine is working well.

Please let me know if you need any more info or clarity on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, if you don't have any image in it, to delete vdocker, then re-create it (with [proxy if you are behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33785208/6309))

Then make sure to [assign it a fixed IP with `dmvbf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130098/6309)

```
dmvbf vdocker 99 101
docker-machine regenerate-certs -f vdocker
```

After that, your VM should start everytime.

Comment: @ChhayaVankhede If you have its Dockerfile, you can delete, recreate and once the IP is fixed, rebuid the tenserflow image